# 'FileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: django

When uploading a file in Django's admin, I'm trying to create and rename a copy of this file using a signal. However, I'm receiving the following error:

'FileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'path'

models

```
class Template(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def org_folder(self, filename):
        path = "templates/%s/%s/%s" % (self.organization.name, self.name, filename)
        return path

    docxfile = models.FileField(upload_to=org_folder)
```

signals

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Template)
def create_clean_docxfile(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if sender is Template:
        file = Template.docxfile.path
        copyfile(file, 'temp.zip')
```

Any recommendations?

**Update**

Per Daniel's recommendation, I cleared the error. I had to update the signal to the following:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Template)
def create_clean_docxfile(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    file = instance.docxfile.path
    copyfile(file, 'temp.zip')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sender is the class. You need to access the instance, which is provided by the instance argument. (And you don't need that if statement.)

```
def create_clean_docxfile(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    file = instance.docxfile.path
    copyfile(file, 'temp.zip')
```